# How to print each word of a string printed as new record?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python.
I have input in this format

```
Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American
Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American
Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American Harry is American
```

And my output should should like this

```
Harry, 1
is, 1
American, 1
Harry, 1
is, 1
American, 1
....
```

Can you please tell me the solution...

I am trying with below code(my code was not even closer to the solution).

```
import sys
import re
inp = open('menu.bak', "r")
outp = open('word.txt',"w")
for line in inp:
  counts = len(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
  new = ''.join(line)
  print(new[0])
  print(new[1])
inp.close()
outp.close()
```

Thanks,
Gokul S

Comment: You mean you just want to print ", 1 " after each word in your input? Why are you using `re` and importing `sys` without using them? What do you think joining a string is going to do for you?

Comment: Yes after each word "1" should be printed and second string should be printed in next line followed by "1".  I used re to count number of strings in a line and using the count I thought i can iterate my for loop count times to print count number of records. Suppose if we have 7 words in a string, in the output i should see 7 words printed in separate lines.

Comment: I got the output. Below is my code

Comment: import re
    inp = open('menu.bak', "r")
    outp = open('word.txt',"w")
    for line in inp:
      for word in line.split():
        outp.write(str(word) + "," + "1" + '\n')
    inp.close()
    outp.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
inp = open('menu.bak', "r")
outp = open('word.txt',"w")
for line in inp:
  for word in line.split():
    outp.write(str(word) + "," + "1" + '\n')
inp.close()
outp.close()
```